# Get last rows before certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table, I have a field `RAZ` (bit) whose value is 0 except at 5am, 1pm and 9pm when it's equal to 1. I would like to get the last rows in my table before `RAZ` is equal to 1.

Here is a sample data :
[image]

For exemple, the final request would display the row with `idEvenement = 8454`.

I will use this request in a stored procedure to compute indicators.

The `RAZ` field changes to 1 automatically, it means that the data has been reset.

I don't know if it's possible and how to do it.

Comment: what sets the RAZ to 1? a stored procedure? obtain the records just before you set the value

Comment: @DaleK just edited my question, sorry for the lack of informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL Server windowing function LEAD to see if the next record's RAZ turns to 1 while it was 0 before. LEAD gets the next record based on RAZTime order. This returns ID = 8454 as the result

```
; WITH cte (ID, RAZTime, RAZ) AS (
          SELECT 8456, convert(datetime, '13:01 pm'), 1
    union SELECT 8455, convert(datetime, '13:00 pm'), 1
    union SELECT 8454, convert(datetime, '12:59 pm'), 0
    union SELECT 8453, convert(datetime, '12:58 pm'), 0
)
, q AS (
    SELECT
       *
       , NextRAZ = LEAD (RAZ, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY RAZTime)
    FROM cte
)
SELECT *
FROM q
WHERE
    RAZ = 0
    AND NextRAZ = 1
```

Comment: Does this method run non-stop ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by non-stop. It evaluates all records at once and find the records you're looking for. If you need to run this daily and only wants to know records in the last few days or so, just expand the WHERE clause for those dates only

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand how it works. However, I do not understand when the NextRAZ field is set to 1.

Comment: realized I made a mistake. fixed it and tested it.